# Python how to export a print view to txt

Tags: python, printing, txt

I have a print that works perfectly to me since I use tabulate:

```
print(tabulate(query, headers= 'keys', tablefmt = 'psql'))
```

And I would like to **export this print to a txt file** just the way it looks in terminal.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way

```
print(tabulate(query, headers= 'keys', tablefmt = 'psql'), file=open("output.txt", "a"))
```